# GoogleIdTokenVerifier kept giving exception

Tags: spring-boot, google-oauth

I am trying to use GoogleIdToekVerifier to vertify access_token in my backend Springboot application.

```
@Configuration
public class googleVerifyConfig
{

    @Bean
    public GoogleIdTokenVerifier googleIdTokenVerifier(@Value("${client_id}") String clientId) {

        NetHttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new GsonFactory();

        return new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(transport, jsonFactory)
                .setAudience(Collections.singletonList(clientId))
                .build();
    }
}
```

Here is where things fails:

```
public UserMetaInfo verifyUSer(String tokenString) throws Exception{

        try {
            GoogleIdToken idToken = googleIdTokenVerifier.verify(tokenString.substring(7));

            if (idToken != null) {
                GoogleIdToken.Payload payload = idToken.getPayload();
                String userId = payload.getSubject();
                String email = payload.getEmail();
                String name = (String)payload.get("name");
                String pictureUrl = (String)payload.get("picture");
                return new UserMetaInfo(email, name, pictureUrl, userId);
            }
            else {
                throw new Exception("idToken is null");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error Message: " + e.getMessage());
            throw new AuthException("Invalid Google Auth");
        }
    }
```

It looks like `GoogleIdToken idToken = googleIdTokenVerifier.verify(tokenString.substring(7));` is giving me exception, but when I print exception in: `System.out.println("Error Message: " + e.getMessage());`. It just give me Error Message: null.

Is there any thing I need to do in application.properties? I have been stuck in this error for two days. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Edit 1: Looks like the issue is I am passing the access_token, not a jwt token. But I am not sure how to convert from one to another

Comment: An access token is not an id token